# What device information can be accessed in android

Tags: java, android, device

I working on an android app which can benefit from device information. Like make, model, API level, resolution, size, installed apps, memory, etc.

Can you direct me to a link which might be useful to learn what all is available and how to access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)

It holds various informations regarding the cellphone (or tablet). You might also need some information that can only be accessed with the proper permissions, so take a look at [this other](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html).

Both links are from android's developers site